# How can I add a message and add a reaction to that message in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to send a message and reactions with `discord.py` (trying to create a poll, with my own BOT) like this:

[image]

This is as far a could go:

[image]

With `$poll`, just call the function. 
Parameters: `"question" "option1" "option2"` ... to 10 options. If the user send more than 10 just ignore them.

I can add the bold text, quote some text (the options part), and insert an emoji inside the text

BUT! I can add a reaction to the message itself to let the users set their opinions.

```
import os
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command(name='poll', help='Create a Poll!')
async def poll(ctx, q : str, *opt):
    bar = ":bar_chart: "
    qu = "> "
    e = "\n"
    c = 0
    opts = ""
    l = [":regional_indicator_a:",
         ":regional_indicator_b:",
         ":regional_indicator_c:",
         ":regional_indicator_d:",
         ":regional_indicator_e:",
         ":regional_indicator_f:",
         ":regional_indicator_g:",
         ":regional_indicator_h:",
         ":regional_indicator_i:",
         ":regional_indicator_j:",
         ":regional_indicator_k:"]
    new_l = [] #This is just to store the name from :name: to name
    question = bar + '**' + q + '**' + e
    for i in opt:
        opts = opts + qu + l[c] + ' ' + i + (e if c <= 9 else "")
        p = str(l[c])
        new_l.append(p[1:-1]) #Here from :name: to name 
        c = c + 1
        if c == 10: break
    response = question + opts
    m = await ctx.send(response)

    # Here is where the error comes... When the user adds the options, 
    #I need to add that emoji as a reaction 
    #(:regional_indicator_a:, and so on, to 10) to 
    #led the user make the vote. 
    #BUT! As you can see, i can not add the reaction! 
    for j in new_l:
        emoji = get(ctx.guild.emojis, name=j)
        await m.add_reaction(emoji)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This is part of the error:

```
Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding emojis, you'll want to use the actual emoji, for example , which you can get from doing `\:emoji_name:` in discord and sending the message:

[image]

Turns into:

[image]

Which you can then copy directly into your IDE.

Alternatively, if your IDE doesn't support emojis, you can use the unicode, which you can find from [this](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_emoticons.html) site. As an example, the unicode for bar chart would be `\u1f4ca`, as the format in python follows the formatting of `\u` as the prefix, followed by its unicode.

This means your list of emojis would look like `["", "", "", ....` or `["\u1f1e6", "\u1f1e7", "\u1f1e8", ....`

Comment: I want to use A,B, C, as you can see in the pictures for the index items (:regional_indicator_a: for example). How can I get the ID or mayby the Unicode of that emoji/reaction?

Comment: I included them as the examples at the end in the lists. You can get them from the website that I linked and searching for the emoji's name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the emoji module.

```
import emoji
```

It has a function that will make the "emojize" the emoji from the chat

```
await add_reaction(emoji.emojize(x)) # where x is the emoji in your chat that your code recieve
```